# Missing route error in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, routes, crud

I'm learning laravel and practice with making simple blog app. I have failed to update an article. My route is missing and going to "my slug route" at bottom of code and throw error.
Error about the slug not found, that's okay. But why my route is missing? My other routes working create,delete etc.
What is my fault?
Note: Sorry for bad english.

**edit.blade.php**

```
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>'update', 'method'=>'patch')) }} 
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $article->id }}"> 
    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" value="{{ $article->title }}" />
    <textarea type="text" name="body" placeholder="Body">{{ $article->body }}</textarea>
    <input type="text" name="tags" placeholder="Tags" value="{{ $article->tags }}" />
    <input type="submit" value="Update" >
{{ Form::close() }}
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::post('update', array(
'uses' => 'HomeController@update'
))->before('auth');

Route::get('/{slug}', function($slug){
setlocale(LC_TIME, "tr,TR", "tr" , "turkish");
$article = Article::where('slug', $slug)->first();
$comments = $article->comments()->where('approve', '=', 1)->get();
$date = $article->created_at;   
$date = iconv('latin5','utf-8',strftime('%A %d %B %Y'));
return View::make('article', array(
    'article' => $article,
    'date' => $date,
    'comments' => $comments
));
});
```

and HomeController.php

```
public function update(){
    $rules = array(
        'title' => 'required|min:5|max:255',
        'body' => 'required|min:10',
        'tags' => 'required|min:5|max:100'
        );
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator);
    }
    $id = Input::get('id');
    $article = Article::find($id);
    $article->title = Input::get('title');
    $article->body = Input::get('body');
    $article->tags = Input::get('tags');
    $article->save();
    return Redirect::back()->with('message', 'Article was updated successfully.');
}
```

Comment: What is the HTML you get from that section of your edit.blade.php?

Answer (score 0):

You have done

```
'method'=>'patch'
```

But your route is

```
Route::post('update'...
```

Change your route to this

```
Route::patch('update'...
```

Comment: I tried but that is still the same error. Url goes to /edit not /update. http://oi59.tinypic.com/j0fvbr.jpg

Answer (score 0):

In your form use this code :

```
Form::open(array('action' => array('HomeController@update', $article->id), 'method' => 'put', ));
```